# Custom Provider for Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, authentication, iis

I would like to know how to develop a custom provider for Windows Authentication. I've an ASP.NET web application served with IIS 8.5 that authenticates using Windows Authentication. The problem is that I also need to authenticate users asking a custom web service (in addition to the local users and active directory)

[image]

How can I achieve this? Forms authentication is not a solution because I need to authenticate in other apps (Reporting Services and Analysis Services) with the same credentials from the ASP.NET app and both application have the authentication and authorization configured with Windows Authentication.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This question can have no answer at all, as products SSAS do not support anything other than NTLM/Kerberos, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/authentication-methodologies-supported-by-analysis-services Even if you hook your provider here in IIS, it won't work.

Comment: OK, I understand that SSAS doesn't allow any custom SSP to authenticate users. But that was my last option. I've a partner that built a WS to authenticate users with their credentials and not with the local users of the server where SSAS is installed. Is somehow this possible?

Comment: It is possible to use advanced technologies such as [Protocol Transition](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj553400(v=ws.11).aspx) to achieve cool things. I am not quite sure if your partner uses a similar approach. If you want to go that route, then there would be very limited resources to refer to.

Comment: Could be the deployment of LDAP a solution for authenticate users in IIS, SSRS and SSAS?